# Django models relationship

Tags: django, django-models

I am working on an aggregator app where I am fetching products from different websites . Each product has a subcategory, color , patten associated to it . (Eg long-sleeve blue horizontal stripe t-shirt.) Here the subcategory is long-sleeved t-shirt and color blue and pattern stripe. I have created models like this

```
 from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import models
from smart_selects.db_fields import ChainedForeignKey,ChainedManyToManyField

# Create your models here.
class Category(models.Model):
    title=models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


class Product(models.Model):
    title=models.CharField(max_length=255)
    price=models.DecimalField(max_digits=10,decimal_places=4,null=True)
    subcategory = models.ForeignKey('Subcategory',related_name='products',null=True,blank=True)
    color =  models.ForeignKey('Color',related_name='productcolor',null=True)
    pattern =  models.ForeignKey('Pattern',related_name='productpattern',null=True)
    image=  models.URLField(null=True,blank=True)
    # outfit=  models.ForeignKey('Outfit',related_name='looks',null=True)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


class Subcategory(models.Model):
    title=models.CharField(max_length=255)
    category = models.ForeignKey('Category',related_name='category',blank=True,null=True)
    # product=  models.ForeignKey('Product',related_name='Productinsub',null=True)
    # outfit=  models.ForeignKey('Outfit',related_name='outlook',null=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "subcatagories"


    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class Color(models.Model):
    title=models.CharField(max_length=255)
    subcategory = models.ManyToManyField('Subcategory',related_name='subcategory',null=True)
    # pattern = models.ForeignKey('Pattern', blank=True, null=True, related_name='colors')


    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class Pattern(models.Model):
    title=models.CharField(max_length=255)
    # color = models.ManyToManyField('Color',related_name='patterns',null=True)
#
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Till this every thing is fine the issue is in front end sidebar I need to show subcategories below that color and underneath pattern. Now when a user selects subcategory for example long-sleeved t-shirt from the sidebar , in color sidebar all the available colors of that particular subcategory should be seen and same goes for pattern. So how do I get all colors from subcategory since there is no direct relationship of colors to subcategory ?

EDIT
i have added my complete model as suggested i have added the relationship but when i upload my csv it is not mapping the many to many fields here is how i map my csv from django -import export

```
class CategoryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
   pass


admin.site.register(Category,CategoryAdmin)

# class LookAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
#    pass
#
#
# admin.site.register(Look,LookAdmin)


@admin.register(models.Subcategory)
class SubcategoryAdmin(bulk_admin.BulkModelAdmin):
    search_fields = ('title',)
    raw_id_fields = ('category',)

# admin.site.register(Subcategory,SubcategoryAdmin)


class ColorAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
   pass

admin.site.register(Color,ColorAdmin)

class ProductWidget(widgets.ForeignKeyWidget):

    def clean(self, value):
        return self.model.objects.get_or_create(title= value)[0]


class ProductResource(resources.ModelResource):

    category = fields.Field(column_name='category', attribute='category', widget=ProductWidget(Category, 'title'))
    subcategory = fields.Field(column_name='subcategory', attribute='subcategory', widget=ProductWidget(Subcategory, 'title'))
    color = fields.Field(column_name='color', attribute='color', widget=ProductWidget(Color, 'title'))
    pattern = fields.Field(column_name='pattern', attribute='pattern', widget=ProductWidget(Pattern, 'title'))


    class Meta:
        model = Product

class ProductAdmin(ImportExportModelAdmin,bulk_admin.BulkModelAdmin):
    resource_class = ProductResource
    list_filter =   ('subcategory', admin.RelatedOnlyFieldListFilter),('color', admin.RelatedOnlyFieldListFilter),('pattern', admin.RelatedOnlyFieldListFilter)
    list_select_related = ('subcategory','color','pattern')
    # raw_id_fields = ('outfit',)
    # bulk_inline =  (ProductInline,)

    # inlines = (OutfitInline,)

admin.site.register(Product,ProductAdmin)
```

my csv file looks like this

```
title      price    category    subcategory color   id
 Stripe Top 899 Top Dress   red 
 Fringe Shoulder Midi Dress 3495    Top Dress   red 
 Button Through Skater Dress    1595    Top Dress   red
```

Comment: It would be easier if you show us the models.

Comment: @JoseRomeroi have added the models

Answer (score 0):

To access from the subcategory to the color model I would use the related_name you have defined.

```
list_of_colors = []
for product in subcategory.products.all():
    list_of_colors.append(product.color)

#And for avoiding repeated colors
list_of_colors = set(list_of_colors)
list_of_colors = list(list_of_colors)
return list_of_colors
```

Not sure if you could do this like

```
#And for avoiding repeated colors
return list(set(list_of_colors))
```

I hope I understood correctly the problem. I don't know if this is the best way to do it... But I hope it helps.

Comment: Have you tried setting all the products with that subcategory `products=subcategory.products_set` and then getting the colors from those products?

Comment: @user2466766 can you elaborate a little I am still very much a beginner in django

Answer (score 0):

In the following i will assume that you are passing the subcategory.id to your view since you said the user selectes the subcategory.

```
views.py:
def YourView(request, subcategory_id)
    subcategory = Subcategory.objects.get(id=subcategory_id)
    products = subcategory.products_set.all()
    context = {'products': products}
    template = 'YourTemplate.html'
    return render(request, context, template)


html:
<div class="btn-group">
    <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        Colors
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
        <ul class="list-group">
        {% for c in products %}
            <button class="list-group-item" type="submit" value="{{ c.color }}" name="some_name">{{ c.color }}</button>
        {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have placed the colors in a button dropdownMenu assuming the user will have to select a color and then something happens. Hope this is what you are looking for.